# what does sys._getframe(0).f_lineno do exactly?

Tags: python, sys

The following is the code. I roughly understand that sys._getframe(i).f_lineno do, if the number i is bigger than 0. So, it's the line number when you actually make the function call. Python interpreter puts it in a stack. That's how you get the ordering. I mean, that's why when you print out, you have the most recent function call first. So, could anyone explain to me what does sys.getframe(0).f_lineno do? I figured it must have something to do with the current python code maybe.

```
import sys

#print(sys.version)
a=sys._getframe(0)
print(a)
def one():
    two()

def two():
    three()

def three():
    for num in range(3):
        frame=sys._getframe(num)
        print(frame.f_lineno)
one()
```

Comment: Your code is not displayed , please check

Comment: @Tarptaeya, I posted the code.

Comment: there is a nice tutorial at http://farmdev.com/src/secrets/framehack/index.html